# Create horizontal and vertical menu inside drop down menu

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do menu similar to Chrome, inside drop down menu I want horizontal menu and vertical together.

[image]

my code:

```
        <div id="mobileMenu" >
        <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="" data-bypass>1</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-bypass>2</a></li>

            <div class="oneLine">
                <div class="row-fluid align-center">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <li><a href="" data-bypass>3</a></li></div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <li><a href="" data-bypass>4</a></li><div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="" data-bypass>5</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-bypass>6</a></li>
            <li><a href="" data-bypass>7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I thought maybe I can create additional class and divide this by different spans, to create one line with "3 and 4" horizontal, but it didn't work.
I tried without spans just with simple css:

```
                .oneLine {
        li {
            display: inline;
a {
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    width:50%;
border-right: 1px solid #969696;}
 }   
   }
```

and it didn't work.
Maybe do you know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nothing like that out of the box in Bootstrap but the dropdown menu component would be where to start. Try again starting with that and you're indicating classes used in Bootstrap 2, Bootstrap 4 is coming out in a few months, so I'd start getting familiar with 3 and using the examples to start

Comment: I know Bootstrap 3, but this particular project all in Bootstrap 2 so I cannot change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a lot possibilities of doing this.

Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/odd1y2nc/1/

```
<ul>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li class="horizontal">Horizontal</li>
    <li class="horizontal">Horizontal</li>
    <li class="horizontal">Horizontal</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
    <li>Vertical</li>
</ul>

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.horizontal {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, in my case it didn't want to work proper without .vertical{clear:both;} after horizontal :)

Comment: Hi, Sansevna. I'm glad to help you. Did you use width: 100% width for the rest of li's?